# Как объединить несколько регулярных выражений в одно?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо было добавить пробелов между  математическими знаками `/*+-` в строке `eq = 'a+b-c/d*30'` и я не придумал, к сожалению ничего лучшего кроме как:

```
eq_new = re.sub(r'[-]', ' - ', eq)
eq_new = re.sub(r'[+]', ' + ', eq_new)
eq_new = re.sub(r'[/]', ' / ', eq_new)
eq_new = re.sub(r'[*]', ' * ', eq_new)
```

Но это явно противоречит DRY. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то сделать из 4х этих выражений одно?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```
re.sub(r'[-+/*]', r' \g<0> ', text)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/LXsaaI/1/). `[-+/*]` находит `-`, `+`, `/` или `*`, а `\g<0>` подставляет текст целого совпадения.

Если пробелы уже существуют в некоторых местах, то можно использовать

```
re.sub(r'\s*([-+/*])\s*', r' \1 ', text)
```

**Подробности**

- `\s*` - 0 и более пробельных символов
- `([-+/*])` - Захватывающая подмаска №1 (`\1` подставляет текст, захваченный этой подмаской, в шаблоне замены): `-`, `+`, `/` или `*`
- `\s*` - 0 и более пробельных символов

Comment: Случайно не вы ставите минусы на мои ответы по регулярным выражениям?

Answer (score 0):

А не проще с помощью str.replace?

```py
s = 'a-a+a/a*a'

replaceable = ('+', '-', '/', '*')

for i in replaceable:
    s = s.replace(i, f' {i} ')
```